# How to figure out the distance between two tags

Tags: jquery

For example I have two tags and I want to know the distance between them, meaning want to know the amount of space between them (assuming there is no content between these tags for now). 
For width think there is a float happening between these two `<h3>` tags. How can I do this?

something like this:

```
<p>A</p> 
^
| distance(height) between these two paragraph in pixel? 
v
<p>B</p>


<h3>A</h3> <--- distance (width) in pixel ?--> <h3>B</h3>
```

Comment: you might want to check out the `.offset()`or `.position()` function. Get both elements offset.top and subtract.

Comment: @user3154108 and subtract the height resp. width of the first element as well.

Comment: @user3154108 is talking about jquery functions, `offset` gives position relative to document, whereas `position` to the parent

Comment: @CBroe yeah, that could be helpful, too.

Comment: run .position() on both elements and then subtract the difference. If they are on different Y coordinates, then you will have to use the distance formula on this page: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/linear-equations-how-to-find-slope-yintercept-dist.html to calculate the distance once you have the X and Y coordinates of both elements.